# What is the value of a delta function?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, dirac-delta

So my understanding is that a delta function $\delta(t)$ has the value of $\infty$ at $t = 0$ and $\delta(t) = 0$ everywhere else. Essentially, it's just one big spike on a graph right?

In my signal processing lecture, I came across the following:

[image]

Here, we arrive at $X_1[k] = \frac{1}{2}\delta [k - 1] + \frac{1}{2}\delta [k + 1]$, which means  $X_1[k]$ only has non-zero value at $k - 1$ and $k + 1$. However, using my definition of a delta function, shouldn't $X_1[k = \pm 1] = \infty$?

This isn't the case when you look at the graph. It shows $X_1[k = \pm 1] = \frac{1}{2}$, so what's wrong? Is there some other delta function I just don't know?

Comment: When the argument is discrete, $\delta(x)$ is usually $\begin{cases} 1 & x=0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ rather than the Dirac delta function. This accomplishes the analogous thing to what the Dirac delta does to integrals, but for sums. People also often consider the Kronecker delta symbol $\delta_{i,j}=\begin{cases} 1 & i=j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$.

Comment: Technically, the real $\delta$ function is not a function - it is an operator. It can be seen as the limit of function operators which are spikes near zero getting thinner and taller, all with area one. But it doesn't make sense to really think of the "value" at zero being infinity, because that wouldn't distinguish it from $\frac{1}{2}\delta.$

Comment: In DSP a $\delta$ means what the first comment says.

Comment: The Dirac delta function, $\delta(t)$, used in continuous time integrals, is different from the Kronecker delta function, $\delta[n]$, used in discrete time summations.  Their effect is the same, an identity element for the convolution operator.

Comment: I suppose I should add that the delta function"s value doesn't matter.  It's properties under integration (or summation for the discrete time version) are what matter.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers here.

1. First, the answer from the classical point of view.

Delta function is defined as something which has the following property:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) f(x)dx=f(0)$$

It is not a function but some special symbol.

Now, $a \delta(x)$ is defined as heaving the following property:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty a\delta(x) f(x)dx=a f(0)$$

That's it.

2. Actually one can consider delta function as a function that takes values from the set of divergent integrals rather than real numbers.

By [definition via Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function),

$$\delta (x-\alpha )={\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{-\infty }^{\infty } \cos(px-p\alpha ) dp$$

This gives formally $\delta(0)=\frac1\pi \int_0^\infty dx$
You can consider this divergent integral the value of Dirac Delta at zero. It is not a real number though.

This way, $a\delta(0)$ would be $\frac1\pi \int_0^\infty a dx$, also a divergent integral.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\eqd}{\triangleq}$
$\newcommand{\eqa}{\approx}$
$\newcommand{\abs}[1]{{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}}$
$\newcommand{\brp}[1]{{\left(#1\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\brs}[1]{{\left[#1\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\brlr}[1]{\left.#1\right|}$
$\newcommand{\brbl}[1]{\left\{#1\right.}$
$\newcommand{\deriv} [2]   {{\frac{\mathrm{d}#1}{\mathrm{d}#2} }}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\Bbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\Z}{\Bbb{Z}}$
$\newcommand{\Rx} {{\R^\ast}}$
$\newcommand{\intcc} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\intoo} [2]  {{\left(#1:#2\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\intoc} [2]  {{\left(#1:#2\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\intco} [2]  {{\left[#1:#2\right)}}$
$\newcommand{\ff}{\mathrm{f}}$
$\newcommand{\fy}{\mathrm{y}}$
$\newcommand{\fF}{\mathrm{F}}$
$\newcommand{\fG}{\mathrm{G}}$
$\newcommand{\fg}{\mathrm{g}}$
$\newcommand{\fphi}{\mathrm{\phi}}$
$\newcommand{\dx}{\mathrm{dx}}$
$\newcommand{\du}{\mathrm{du}}$
$\newcommand{\dv}{\mathrm{dv}}$
$\newcommand{\dt}{\mathrm{dt}}$
$\newcommand{\dtau}{\mathrm{d\tau}}$
$\newcommand{\kdelta}{\bar{\delta}}$
$\newcommand{\setu}{\cup}$
$\newcommand{\setn}[1]{{\left\{{#1}\right\}}}$
$\newcommand{\seqn}[1]{{\left[{#1}\right]}}$
$\newcommand{\inprod}[2]{\left\langle{#1}\,|\,{#2}\right\rangle}$

Building on what others have already said, the two functions are just that—two distinct functions.
One is the real-valued *Kronecker Delta* function $\kdelta:\Z\to\R$ defined as
$$\kdelta(n)\eqd\brbl{\begin{array}{cl}
  1 & \text{if $n=0$}\\
  0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}}$$
and the other is the *Dirac Delta* $\delta:\R\to\Rx$, which obviously is *not* a real-valued function at all.
This is not so much a problem in and of itself
(functions can be mappings to real numbers, complex numbers, colors, faces of a die, ...)
but in the case of $\delta$, it maps not into a well behaved set like the real numbers $\R$,
but rather into the set of
[extended real numbers](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0792336585&pg=PA8)
$\Rx\eqd\R\setu\setn{-\infty,+\infty}$.
The set $\Rx$ is an Alice-in-Wonderland type world and when working therein requires great care
and proper safety equipment.
In $\Rx$ crazy things can happen like $\infty+\infty=\infty$.

Because $\delta(x)$ maps to $\Rx$, many would not call it a *function* at all, but rather an
*extended function*, or a distribution
(see for example [Mallat](https://books.google.com/books?id=hbVOfWQNtB8C) Appendix A.7).
A distribution may be something of a loose cannon when left to its own devices,
but when constrained to the inside of an integral
(or more generally inside an inner product)
it becomes quite well-behaved, predictable, and useful.

Building on what @Anixx and @Thomas-Andrews have already pointed out,
the Dirac Delta distribution can be defined, together with $\int\dx$, as an
*operator* (a [mapping](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0817646868&pg=PA42) from one
[linear space](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0817641742) to another/same linear space)
with the following [definition](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN0521649714):
$$\inprod{\ff(x)}{\delta(x)} \eqd \int_{\R}\ff(x)\delta(x)\dx \eqd \ff(0)$$

So the Dirac Delta distribution $\delta(x)$ and the Kronecker delta function are distinctly different.
But that being said (that they are very different in form), they are very similar in function.
In particular, note the following:

(1) Both "sum" to 1:
\begin{align*}
  \boxed{\int_{\R} \delta(x)\dx}
    &= \int_{\R} 1\cdot\delta(x)\dx
  \\&\eqd \boxed{1}
    && \text{by definition of $\delta$}
  \\
  \\
  \boxed{\sum_{n\in\Z}\kdelta(n)}
    &= \kdelta(0)
    && \text{by definition of $\kdelta$}
  \\&= \boxed{1}
\end{align*}

(2) Both have a similar time-shift property:
\begin{align*}
   \boxed{\int_{\R} \delta\brp{x-a}\ff(x)\dx}
     &= \int_\R \delta\brp{u}\ff(u+a)\du
     && \text{where $u=x-a$ $\implies$ $\dx=\du$}
   \\&= \boxed{\ff(a)}
  \\
  \\
  \boxed{\sum_{n\in\Z}\kdelta(n-k)y(n)}
    &= \sum_{n\in\Z}\kdelta(m)y(m+k)
    && \text{where $m=n-k$ $\implies$ $n=m+k$}
  \\&= \kdelta(0)y(0+k)
    && \text{by definition of $\kdelta$}
  \\&= \boxed{y(k)}
\end{align*}

(3) Both induce a projection operator.
A projection operator $P$ is a linear operator [such that](https://books.google.com/books?id=yzr0BwAAQBAJ&pg=PA73)
$P^2=P$:
\begin{align*}
  \boxed{P^2}\ff(x)
    &= PP\ff(x)
  \\&\eqd P\int_\R \delta(x)\ff(x) \dx
    && \text{where here $P$ is the Dirac Delta operator}
  \\&\eqd P\ff(0)
    && \text{by definition of $\delta$}
  \\&\eqd \int_\R \delta(x)\ff(0)\dx
    && \text{where here $P$ is the Dirac Delta operator}
  \\&= \ff(0) \int_\R \delta(x)\dx
    && \text{by linearity of the integral operator}
  \\&= \ff(0)
    && \text{because $\int_{\R} \delta(x)\dx=1$}
  \\&= \int_\R\delta(x)\ff(x)\dx
    && \text{by definition of $\delta$}
  \\&= \boxed{P}\ff(x)
    && \text{where here $P$ is the Dirac Delta operator}
  \\
  \\
  \boxed{P^2}\fy(n)
    &= PP\fy(n)
  \\&\eqd P\sum_{n\in\Z} \kdelta(n)\fy(n) 
    && \text{where here $P$ is the Kronecker Delta operator}
  \\&\eqd P\fy(0)
    && \text{by definition of $\kdelta$}
  \\&\eqd \sum_{n\in\Z} \kdelta(n)\fy(0)
    && \text{where here $P$ is the Kronecker Delta operator}
  \\&= \fy(0) \sum_{n\in\Z} \kdelta(n)
    && \text{by linearity of the summation operator}
  \\&= \fy(0)
    && \text{because $\sum_{n\in\Z} \kdelta(n)=1$}
  \\&= \sum_{n\in\Z}\kdelta(n)\fy(n)
    && \text{by definition of $\kdelta$}
  \\&= \boxed{P}\fy(n)
    && \text{where here $P$ is the Kronecker Delta operator}
\end{align*}

(4) Both can be used for sampling.
The Dirac can be used—inside an integral—as a projection operator to map
a function $\ff(t)$ to a single point $\ff(a)$ for some value $t=a$.
That is, it can be used to *sample* $\ff(t)$ at a given time $t=a$.
In the field of Digital Signal Processing
(DSP) a continuous time function $\ff(t)$ can be transformed (mapped) to a
sequence
([a function with domain $\Z$](https://books.google.com/books?vid=ISBN8122408265&pg=PA31))
$\seqn{\ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n, x_{n+1}, \ldots}$,
where each element $x_k$ of this sequence is
$$x_k \eqd \int_\R \ff(t)\delta(t-kT)\dt = \ff(kT)$$
Likewise, the Kronecker delta can be used to sample (OK, maybe a bit of a stretch here?)
a sequence $\seqn{\ldots, x_{n-1}, x_n, x_{n+1}, \ldots}$
in the sense
$$y(n)= \cdots + x_{-2}\kdelta(n+2) + x_{-1}\kdelta(n+1) + x_0\kdelta(n) + x_1\kdelta(n-1) + x_2\kdelta(n-2) + \cdots$$